# Is it safe to keep an unused iOS5 method in target iOS 3+ code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Environment: Base iOS: 5.1
             Target iOS: 3.0

Greetings:
I have added the iOS 5+ UIViewController API:

```
    - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)...
```

adjacent to the pre-iOS 5.0:

```
   - (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)...
```

within a host view controller, with the intent of eventually using it.

We're currently only using the older (pre-iOS 5.0) method.

However there are concerns that problems may arise during deployment (ObjC's runtime selector handing, etc.) in an iOS 3.0
environment due to this API.

Is there a concern here?

Ric.

Comment: Do you mean you categoried your own implementation of `presentViewController:` onto UIViewController?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the code in the file, so long as it isn't executed on anything before iOS 5.
if you want you can test using something like

```
[NSObject respondsToSelector:@selector(foobar)];
```

Comment: We're working on a large project that has to support a fairly wide iOS spectrum.  Eventually the lower end of that spectrum will be deprecated and drop off; as we try to incorporate more-modern API.

We don't want to break the lower iOS environment in preference for support for the more-recent iOSes.  If we could safely load more modern APIs & support the lower echelon... that's the preferred way.

We could also weak-link the new frameworks.  But at present, we'll stay with the up-to-date foundation frameworks whilst supporting the older iOSes... as far a we can.